# Laravel 5.1 Composer install error

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, composer-php, laravel-artisan

When running `composer install` I get the following error:

```
php artisan clear-compiled
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught TypeError: Argument 1 passed to App\Exceptions\Handler::report() must be an instance of Exception, instance of Error given, called in /home/vagrant/Code/courtesy-sys/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Bootstrap/HandleExceptions.php on line 73 and defined in /home/vagrant/Code/courtesy-sys/app/Exceptions/Handler.php:25
Stack trace:
#0 /home/vagrant/Code/courtesy-sys/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Bootstrap/HandleExceptions.php(73): App\Exceptions\Handler->report(Object(Error))
#1 [internal function]: Illuminate\Foundation\Bootstrap\HandleExceptions->handleException(Object(Error))
#2 {main}
thrown in /home/vagrant/Code/courtesy-sys/app/Exceptions/Handler.php on line 25



[Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalErrorException]                                                                                                                                                         
Uncaught TypeError: Argument 1 passed to App\Exceptions\Handler::report() must be an instance of Exception, instance of Error given, called in /home/vagrant/Code/courtesy-sys/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Bootstrap/HandleExceptions.php on line 73 and defined in /home/vagrant/Code/courtesy-sys/app/Exceptions/Handler.php:25
Stack trace:                                                                                                                                                                                                    
#0 /home/vagrant/Code/courtesy-sys/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Bootstrap/HandleExceptions.php(73): App\Exceptions\Handler->report(Object(Error))                                         
#1 [internal function]: Illuminate\Foundation\Bootstrap\HandleExceptions->handleException(Object(Error))                                                                                                        
#2 {main}                                                                                                                                                                                                       
thrown                                                                                                                                                                                                        



Script php artisan clear-compiled handling the post-install-cmd event returned with error code 255
```

Is there someone with a similar problem and can provide me with the solution. I tried Google without any results...

Answer (score 0):

Try it:

```
composer install --no-scripts
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply it had something to do with PHP7 they are handling errors differently